# How can an Outlook add-in detect if email was sent by the same add-in?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

How can I add "XYZ 1.2.3" (add-in name/version/etc) to an Outlook email message so that if the recipient has the same add-in some additional behavior can be invoked when received? I'd prefer to accomplish this silently to the average user (not through an attachment). Can I do this by modifying the header? If so, would that cause a higher proportion of false spam flags?

I'm using C# with Outlook/VS 2010.

Comment: store a GUID unique to your add-in, in the message?

Comment: @Mitch: Maybe I'm missing something, but how is that "silently to the... user"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the users are allowing HTML, You could append a div:

```
<div id="XYZ 1.2.3"></div>
```

Then your add-in could look for this in incoming emails - the user wouldn't see it.

Comment: in case of msg, you can use named properties or custom mapi properties to do that.Here is the msg format description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912(v=exchg.80).aspx